# Programmatically send use to different endpoint

Tags: javascript

Say the user is on `http://example.com/dashboard`, How would I programmatically change the endpoint without affecting the root url, ie. on an event the user would be sent to `http://example.com/section`.

My issue is is that the URL root can sometimes change depending on the client or the server. So I can't hard code it in.

```
http://sub.example.com/dashboard
http://dev-example.com/dashboard
http://production-example.com/dashboard
```

How do I get the root of the URL and swap in my new endpoint and then redirect the user?

Comment: I'm not sure if that works for you, but have you tried something like this: `$('#elem').on('click', () => location.assign('/some/path'));`?

Comment: When you first get `URL` split that `const urlParts = url.split("/").slice(0, -1)` and set the result as `baseUrl = urlParts.join("/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) .You can build your url with help of window location api object
[image]

```js
function redirect(endpoint){
var paths = window.location;
var url = `${paths.origin}/${endpoint}`
return url

//for page redirect use window.location.href = url
}





console.log(redirect('one'))
console.log(redirect('two'))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the root URL using window.location.origin
2. Concat that string with whatever endpoint you want to add
3. Assign that to window.location.href inside your click event listener
   callback function

So the code will look something like this:

```
const BASE_URL = window.location.origin

document.querySelector('#yourButtonId').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = BASE_URL + '/your_end_point';
}
```

Refer: [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)     [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) to load another URL:

```
$('#elem').on('click', () => location.assign('/some/path'));
```

This will redirect you to `/some/path` on `$('#elem')` click (assuming you use jQuery, but that doesn't matter really)