# Redirects page base on user country (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, userlocation

I’m struggling to find a good resource on how to execute this. I wanted to redirect the page base on user location. I know this required custom code but at the moment I’m stuck with it and most of the resources that I found are outdated. I’m using ipinfo.io to determine the user country.

Here’s the code that I’m using :

```
$.get(“https://ipinfo.io”, function(data) {
if(data.country !== “GB”){
console.log(“no gb”)
}else {
var test
test = ‘GB’
console.log(“THIS IS GB”)}
}, “jsonp”);
```

But then I’m stuck on how to use those value and redirect the page.

If anyone has any experience on this please guide me :pray:t3:

Comment: what is the problem using ipinfo?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406787/programamtically-send-use-to-different-endpoint/58406879#58406879

Comment: The quotes you're using, `“`, `”`, `‘` and `’` are not valid in JS. You need to use `"` and `'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect use `location.href`

```
$.get('https://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
  if(data.country !== “GB”){
    location.href = 'http://ADDRESS-TO-GB'
  } else {
    location.href = 'http://ADDRESS-TO-ANYWHERE'
}, 'jsonp');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){

  $.get( "https://ipapi.co/json/", function( data ) {
    switch(data.country){
      case 'US':
        window.location = 'http://www.google.us';
      break;
      case 'KR':
        window.location = 'http://www.google.kr';
      break;
      default:
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
      break;

    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can use a switch case to do redirection base on the callback received data.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
  if(data.country == 'America'){
    location = 'your_redirect_url';
    return;
  }else if(data.country == 'Beijing'){
    location = 'your_redirect_url';
    return;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **$.getJSON** function then **location.href** to redirect.

```
$.getJSON( "https://ipapi.co/json/", function( data ) {
   if(data.country !== "GB"){ location.href="your site url"}
   if(data.country !== "US"){location.href="your site url"}
  });
```